# ios cell content pushed down when reach top of table

Tags: ios, interface-builder

[image: Cell content pushed down when reach top of table]

I tried tweaking the following attributes to no avail:

- `Preserver super view margin`
- `Safe Area relative margin`

The content inside my `UITableViewCell` has the following constraints:
[image: UITableViewCell constraints]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out..

The top constraint was set to `safe area` which pushes the content down when leaving the screen. Changing it to `superview` gives the expected outcome.

[image: Top constraint change from safe area to superview]